# How to reset a requestanimationframe in a canvas without having to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, canvas

l do seem to have an issue regarding that l can not seem to find a way to reset the canvas object, being the car, once it has reached it's target, instead l'm forced to refresh the page in-order to restart the animation.

There is a reproducible demo below.

```js
const loadImg = url => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.onerror = reject;
  img.onload = () => resolve(img);
  img.src = url;
});

const images = [
  "https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/hand-painted-watercolor-background-with-sky-clouds-shape_24972-1095.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk0DW.png",
];
Promise
  .all(images.map(loadImg))
  .then(([backgroundImg, carImg]) => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("c");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const car = {
      x: canvas.width,
      y: 0
    };

    (function update() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      ctx.drawImage(
        backgroundImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height
      );
      ctx.drawImage(
        carImg, car.x, car.y, carImg.width, carImg.height
      );
      car.x -= 5;

      if (car.x > 200) {
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
      }
    })();
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<canvas id="c" width="970" height="550"></canvas>

<img style="display: none;" id="the_button" src="https://i.imgur.com/wO7Wc2w.png" />

<img style="display: none;" id="the_background" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/hand-painted-watercolor-background-with-sky-clouds-shape_24972-1095.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg" />

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Refactor the code inside the promise (to `driveCar`).
2. Store the images in global variables `backgroundImg`, `carImg`.
3. Now you can call `driveCar()` from somewhere else, in this case a mouse click.
4. You should probably store the images in the promise, but I wanted to show a pattern of how promises could be constructured.

```js
const loadImg = url => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.onerror = reject;
  img.onload = () => resolve(img);
  img.src = url;
});

var backgroundImg, carImg;

const driveCar = ([_backgroundImg, _carImg]) => {   // 2
   backgroundImg = _backgroundImg || backgroundImg; // 3
   carImg = _carImg || carImg;
   
   const canvas = document.getElementById("c");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const car = {
      x: canvas.width,
      y: 0
    };

    (function update() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      ctx.drawImage(
        backgroundImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height
      );
      ctx.drawImage(
        carImg, car.x, car.y, carImg.width, carImg.height
      );
      car.x -= 5;

      if (car.x > 200) {
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
      }
    })();
}

const images = [
  "https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/hand-painted-watercolor-background-with-sky-clouds-shape_24972-1095.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk0DW.png",
];
Promise
  .all(images.map(loadImg))
  .then(driveCar)                    // 4
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
  
document.addEventListener('click', () => { driveCar([]) }); // 3
```

```html
<html>
<canvas id="c" width="970" height="550"></canvas>

<img style="display: none;" id="the_button" src="https://i.imgur.com/wO7Wc2w.png" />

<img style="display: none;" id="the_background" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/hand-painted-watercolor-background-with-sky-clouds-shape_24972-1095.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg" />

</html>
```